# Python / Read and group data from text file with Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text, nlp

I have a text file as follows:

```
Sentence:1 Polarity:N 5puan verdim o da anistonun güzel yüzünün hatırına.
Sentence:2 Polarity:N son derece sıkıcı bir filim olduğunu söyleyebilirim.
Sentence:3 Polarity:N ..saçma bir konuyu nasılda filim yapmışlar maşallah
Sentence:4 Polarity:P bence hoş vakit geçirmek için seyredilebilir.
Sentence:5 Polarity:P hoş ve sevimli bir film.
Sentence:6 Polarity:O eşcinsellere pek sempati duymamakla beraber bu filmde sanki onları sevimli göstermeye çalışmışlar gibi geldi.
Sentence:7 Polarity:O itici bir film değildi sonuçta.
Sentence:8 Polarity:N seyrederken bu kadar sinirlendiğim film hatırlamıyorum.
Sentence:9 Polarity:O  J.Aniston ın hiç mi umut yok diye sorduğu sahnede kıracaktım televizyonu!
Sentence:10 Polarity:O kimse yazmamış ben yazıyım:)
Sentence:11 Polarity:P  güzel bi pazar günü şirin bi film izlemek isteyenler için çok güzel.
```

I want to split this data in to a table like this:

```
Sentence_No - Sentence_Polarity - Sentence_txt
1 - N - 5puan verdim o da anistonun güzel yüzünün hatırına.
2 - N - son derece sıkıcı bir filim olduğunu söyleyebilirim.
3 - N - ..saçma bir konuyu nasılda filim yapmışlar maşallah
4 - P - bence hoş vakit geçirmek için seyredilebilir.
```

So I think I need to get the part from after "Sentence:", "Polarity" and the last txt part. I want it this way so I can classify the data.

I wrote the code below but it is not working for this purpose:

```
df = pd.read_csv('SU-Movie-Reviews-Sentences.txt', lineterminator='\n', names=['Sentence_No', 'Sentence_Polarity' , 'Sentence_txt'])
```

Comment: If Sentence and Polarity never occur in the text, you could just replace them via built-in function

Comment: They never occur in the text, but how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DataFrame's `replace` method with `regex` , and use `header=None` while reading your file with `read_csv` as by default your first line of dataset will be considered as header and you will not able to get the First line. So, use  `fillna("0")` as your number sequence is not consistent and having empty or Nan:

`df = pd.read_csv("SU-Movie-Reviews-Sentences.txt", header=None).fillna("0")`

```
print(df)
                                                   0
0   Sentence:1 Polarity:N 5puan verdim o da anisto...
1   Sentence:2 Polarity:N son derece sıkıcı bir fi...
2   Sentence:3 Polarity:N ..saçma bir konuyu nasıl...
3   Sentence:4 Polarity:P bence hoş vakit geçirmek...
4      Sentence:5 Polarity:P hoş ve sevimli bir film.
5   Sentence:6 Polarity:O eşcinsellere pek sempati...
6   Sentence:7 Polarity:O itici bir film değildi s...
7   Sentence:8 Polarity:N seyrederken bu kadar sin...
8   Sentence:9 Polarity:O  J.Aniston ın hiç mi umu...
9   Sentence:10 Polarity:O kimse yazmamış ben yazı...
10  Sentence:11 Polarity:P  güzel bi pazar günü şi...
```

**Below is How you will use `replace`** :

```
>>> df.replace('Sentence:|Polarity:', '',regex=True)
                                                    0
0   1 N 5puan verdim o da anistonun güzel yüzünün ...
1   2 N son derece sıkıcı bir filim olduğunu söyle...
2   3 N ..saçma bir konuyu nasılda filim yapmışlar...
3   4 P bence hoş vakit geçirmek için seyredilebilir.
4                        5 P hoş ve sevimli bir film.
5   6 O eşcinsellere pek sempati duymamakla berabe...
6                 7 O itici bir film değildi sonuçta.
7   8 N seyrederken bu kadar sinirlendiğim film ha...
8   9 O  J.Aniston ın hiç mi umut yok diye sorduğu...
9                   10 O kimse yazmamış ben yazıyım:)
10  11 P  güzel bi pazar günü şirin bi film izleme...
```

Answer (score 1):

I took this as a test string:

```
test = """Sentence:1 Polarity:N 5puan verdim o da anistonun güzel yüzünün hatırına.
Sentence:2 Polarity:N son derece sıkıcı bir filim olduğunu söyleyebilirim.
Sentence:3 Polarity:N ..saçma bir konuyu nasılda filim yapmışlar maşallah
Sentence:4 Polarity:P bence hoş vakit geçirmek için seyredilebilir."""
```

Using Python's `re` module you can replace what you want using `re.sub`:

```
new_string = re.sub(r"Sentence:(\d+) Polarity:(\w)", r"\1 - \2 -", test)
```

gives you the format you want. `\1` or `\2` are the numbers that matched with the group `(\d+)` or the letter that matched with `(\w)`, respectively.

Now you can work with your new string.